# Quick Launch Toolbar in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, toolbar

To open multiple instances of applications know that pinning isn’t always ideal. So how to enable the Quick Launch Toolbar in Windows 8?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Right-click on the taskbar, choose Toolbars → New Toolbar
2. Enter the path to the folder:
   `%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Quick Launch`
3. Then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
4. Right-click on the taskbar, untick "Lock the Taskbar"
5. Then right-click in the Quick Launch location and uncheck "Show Text" and "Show Title"

Comment: Like in Windows 7: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-7/add-the-quick-launch-bar-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/

Answer (score 2):

Instead of creating a new toolbar, you can in fact open multiple instances of an application from a shortcut pinned to the taskbar. Simply hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> as you click the pinned application and a new instance will be opened.

This also works from within the new Start screen for desktop applications.